# Is there a way to estimate the current life of my ancient phones battery?

Tags: android, battery, battery-life

I have a 3 year old S2 and I wonder if there is a way to estimate how much weaker than new the battery is right now? Something like a percentage (50% of new) or effective capacity(1000 mAh). Is this possible via an app and is there such an app?

Comment: Apps that display mA usage are dependant on the hardware presenting that data. 3years old li-ion is likely at end of life.  80% capacity is deemed by battery experts to be EOL for a li-ion battery, the safety of them is reduced greatly at that point because of 3-4 factors that occur due to general age.  An app called CoolTool can show battery consumption in mA per hour, play a movie with an average mA reading, guess the rest. Many of the "battery saver" apps will also display a capacity , real or assumed.  You already know :-)  replace it to be safe.

Comment: @Psycogeek Safety hmm, an angle i had not considered.. I will give it some thought, thanks!